# Oracle. Return correct record based on fields values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

From the previous post, someone was already helpful and helped me out to create this select which returns 1 record by max. `festpae_id`

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT discount, osp_id, sero_id, estpt_id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY osp_id, sero_id, estpt_id ORDER BY festpae_id DESC) as festpae_id 
      FROM database1 data1
      JOIN database2 data2 ON data2.id = data1.attr_id
     WHERE data1.interest_rate = 1 
       AND data1.ordet_id = data2.id
       AND data1.objt_attr_id = data2.objt_attr_id 
   )
  WHERE festpae_id = 1
```

Records:

```
DISCOUNT     OSP_ID    SERO_ID   ESTPT_ID FESTPAE_ID   VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      50     619356    3931831       2144    NULL       0
      40     619356    3931831       2144    NULL       1
      30     619356    3931831       2144    2000743    0
      15     619356    3931831       2144    2000744    1
```

So from that select, I will get this record

```
DISCOUNT     OSP_ID    SERO_ID   ESTPT_ID FESTPAE_ID   VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      50     619356    3931831       2144    NULL       0
```

For now, I'm having more conditions witch should be checked and my mind has blown out, plus my oracle knowledge is not good enough.

So what do I need? As you can see there are 2 columns called `value` and `festpae_id`. They must be taken into condition.

1. If records exist where `festpae_id is NULL`, then he should check all records where `festpae_id is NULL` and `value = 1` and return record if exists.
2. If there is no records where `festpae_id is null`, then select should return the record with `MAX(festpae_id)` (in this case ROW_NUMBER() is used) and where `value = 1`.
3. In other cases, select should return nothing.

I know, that it could be done via `DECODE()`, but then I need to copy-paste the code witch is not OK. Maybe someone of you could be so kind and share his thoughts about the solution? Working on this for at least 5 hours now and can't find a way how to make it.

P.S This select is used in the view table as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adjust the `order by` and add `value = 1` to the `WHERE`:

```
      (PARTITION BY osp_id, sero_id, estpt_id
       ORDER BY (CASE WHEN festpae_id IS NULL
                      THEN 1 ELSE 2
                 END),
                festpae_id DESC
      ) as festpae_id
```

And:

```
WHERE data1.interest_rate AND value = 1
```

You can also add the `WHERE` condition and simplify the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY testpae_id DESC NULLS FIRST`.